# Hot water heat zone valve

Tags: heat

The hot water baseboard in my apartment stays warm when the heat is off. It is working but does not completely turn off. The head on the zone valve has been replaced. Is this normal or should the base board  shut off  completely.

Comment: How long does it stay warm?  There is residual heat in the water long after the boiler shuts off.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the pipe layout between the baseboard and the boiler, it's not too uncommon for the baseboard closest to the boiler (typically) to have an inadvertent thermosiphon when off, which can cause the temperature to rise above the setpoint of the thermostat.

If the temperature is **not** rising above the setpoint, see @ratchet freak's answer and @JACK's comment

Answer (score 0):

Water has a very high heat capacity. This means that, after the hot water stops flowing when the heat shuts off, it will remain sitting in the radiator radiating heat into the room.

This is by design and why a thermostat tends to shut off the heat a few degrees early because it expects an overshoot.

Answer (score 0):

hot water baseboard in my **apartment** stays warm when the heat is off...

ghost flow

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23CQiEt5QWc

https://www.pmmag.com/articles/98167-how-to-eliminate-ghost-flow-and-recirculation-issues

https://www.fiainc.com/sites/default/files/Unwanted%20Heat%20in%20a%20Zone%20-%20Check%20for%20Ghost%20Flows....pdf

https://www.hearth.com/talk/threads/how-to-eliminate-ghost-flows.39940/